# Rails 5 - show block on check box

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails view (am new to rails), I want to show a div when a check box is set to true.

How should I do that?

I thought of using

`<%= check_box_tag 'advancedtagging', false %> Tag details`

combined with:

```
<% if advancedtagging = '1' %>
<div class="row">
    <%= render 'tags/advanced', :object => @annotation %>
</div>
<% end -%>
```

This is my view:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div data-spy="affix">
            <%= link_to 'Close', annotation_path(@annotation), :class => "btn btn-link" %>
            <%= link_to 'List' , annotations_path, :class => "btn btn-link" %>
            <%= check_box_tag 'advancedtagging', false %> Tag details
            <%= render 'tags/form', :object => @annotation %>
            <br>
        <div class="panel panel-default" id="annotationResults">
            <%= render 'tags/tag_list', :object => @annotation %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-8" id="file">
    <%= content_tag :iframe, nil, src: pdf_annotation_path(@annotation), width: "100%", height: "875px", frameBorder: "0" %>
</div>
</div>

<% if advancedtagging = '1' %>
<div class="row">
    <%= render 'tags/advanced', :object => @annotation %>
</div>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: You will need to use jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an **id** to your div and your checkbox

```
<div id="mydiv" class="row">
    <%= render 'tags/advanced', :object => @annotation %>
</div>
```

**Using Jquery**

```
$(function() {
  $('#mycheckbox').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('div#mydiv').toggle();
  });
});
```

Add your CSS file `div.hidden { display: none; }`

**Using pure js**

Add in some js file for example application.js or other you want

```
$(function() {
    var mycheckbox = document.getElementById('mycheckbox');
    var mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    var toggleDiv = function(){
        if(mycheckbox.checked) {
            mydiv.style['display'] = 'block';
        } else {
            mydiv.style['display'] = 'none';
        }
    }
    mycheckbox.onclick = toggleDiv;
    toggleDiv();
});
```